# Connect via SSH to SLES12 installation

Tags: ssh, installation, sles, automated-install, autoyast

I am trying to make unattended installation but with SSH connectivity, so I can connect remotely and check installation logs.

I know about `usessh=1` kernel parameter, but this makes installation wait for me to start both stages. Without `usessh=1`, there seems to be no appropriate services available. Thought it might be issue with firewall, but there seems to be no firewall service either.

If I connect e.g. using KVM, running `yast module` on second console just invokes the installation again on that console, so configuring using YaST is not possible.

Is there any way to have fully automatic installation, but with possibility to connect to it through SSH?